# How to add same results in one column - Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am making a chart using chart.js and I stumbled across small problem.
With help of for and if, I get values from my table in an array -> example [2,3,4,5,4,5...]
The only numbers possible in table are in range of 1 to 5.
But table looks like this: 2,3,5,4, and it stops there.

How to just add more values into chart, for example, if I have four of 5, and others numbers (1,2,3,4) I have only one, then make bar five longest...

Code for putting values from table into array:

```
for (let i = 0; i < inputNav.length; i++) {
    if(inputNav[i].innerHTML != '') {
        inputValNav = inputNav[i].innerHTML;
        yNav.push(inputValNav);
   }
}
```

Code for chart.js:

```
new Chart("chartnavigation", {
    type: "bar",
    data: {
      labels: xNav,
      datasets: [{
        backgroundColor: barColors,
        barPercentage: 0.5,
        data: yNav
      }]
    },
    options: {
      legend: {display: false},
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: "Title"
      },
      scales: {
        y: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

I am new to chart.js so any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the values of `xNav` are 1 to 5. Then define `data` as an Object to store each count of values from `xNav`, then iterate it based on `inputVal` array to get each count.

```js
let inputNav = document.getElementsByClassName('inputNav');
let xNav = [1,2,3,4,5];
let data = {};
let barColors = ['green','red','orange','yellow']; // define this at the number of colors you want

xNav.forEach((x) => { data[x] = 0; });
for (let i = 0; i < inputNav.length; i++) {
  inputValNav = inputNav[i].innerHTML;
  if(inputValNav !== '') {
    data[inputValNav]++;
  }
}
let yNav = Object.values(data);

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartnavigation').getContext('2d');

new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "bar",
    data: {
      labels: xNav,
      datasets: [{
        label: 'data',
        backgroundColor: barColors,
        barPercentage: 0.5,
        data: yNav
      }]
    },
    options: {
      legend: {display: false},
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: "Title"
      },
      scales: {
        y: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.js"></script>
<div>Data :</div>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="inputNav">2</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="inputNav">3</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="inputNav">4</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="inputNav">5</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="inputNav">4</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="inputNav">5</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="inputNav">5</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="inputNav">5</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="inputNav">5</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="inputNav">5</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="inputNav">5</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="inputNav">5</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<canvas id="chartnavigation"></canvas>
```

Comment: That helped a little bit. Thank You for your time.
But X axis should be only 1 to 5, and Y to change to maximum (in the next example it is number 8). For example, in table columns we have: 2,3,4,5,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5 - so chart should look like 1 on X and 0 on Y (cuz we dont have 1 in table), next 2X 1Y (we have only one number 2 in table), 3X 1Y (we also have only 1 three in table), 4X 2Y (we have 2 of four) and last one 5X 8Y...